# cannot satisfy -package yesod-1.6.0

Tags: haskell, yesod, haskell-stack

I am trying to create a hello world yesod web application and encounter the error message

```
cannot satisfy -package yesod-1.6.0
```

What I've done is, create a project with `stack new yeplay` and then in the package.yaml file I put, `yesod` in the dependencies section, that looks as following:

```
executables:
  yeplay-exe:
    main:                Main.hs
    source-dirs:         app
    ghc-options:
    - -threaded
    - -rtsopts
    - -with-rtsopts=-N
    dependencies:
    - yeplay
    - yesod
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a yeplay.cabal file?  It looks like package.yaml is an hpack thing which I admittedly haven't tried yet.  If you add `, yesod` to your build-depends section in yeplay.cabal it should build.

Comment: How did you create the project ? You can use create using prebaked templates like this: `stack new yeplay yesodweb/simple`. List of yesod based templates are here: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack-templates/wiki#yesod

Comment: It may help to include the entire error message.  Additional verbose output also might help...